# Extended class and static variable

Tags: java, inheritance, static, extends

I've `DynamicObject`, `Player`, `Enemy` classes

```
public class DynamicObject {

    protected static float speed;
}



public class Player extends DynamicObject {
       /*some code*/
       Player.speed = 100;
}


public class Enemy extends DynamicObject {
       /*some code*/
       Enemy.speed = 50;
}
```

And always `speed` value is overridden. Of course I can create new `speed` variable in `Player` and `Enemy`, but then the existing `DynamicObject` class is pointless. I want to have different `speed` values on each class. All objects of current class will have the same `speed`. How I should make it in correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `speed` variable should not be `static`. Otherwise it won't be bound to any of the instances of the `DynamicObject` class, nor any of it's subclasses instances.

If you want to have a different `speed` value for each of the subclasses, you can do:

```
public class DynamicObject {    
    protected float speed;

    public DynamicObject(float speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public float getSpeed() {
       return this.speed;
    }
}

public class Player extends DynamicObject {
   /*some code*/
   public Player(float speed) {
       super(speed);
   }

}


public class Enemy extends DynamicObject {
       /*some code*/
   public Enemy(float speed) {
       super(speed);
   }
}
```

Comment: The getSpeed() method should be in the superclass, not in every subclass, since it always returns the value of a field of the superclass. And I don't see the point in having a variable in each instance, since the speed is the same for all instances of a given class.

Answer (score 4):

If every DynamicObject has a speed, and the speed is the same for every instance of, for example, Player, then you should have

```
public abstract int getSpeed();
```

in DynamicObject, and

```
@Override
public int getSpeed() {
    return 100;
}
```

in Player.

If you need to have access to the constant speed returned for evry instance of Player without instantiateing a Player, just use

```
public static final int CONSTANT_PLAYER_SPEED = 100;

@Override
public int getSpeed() {
    return 100;
}
```

and use `Player.CONSTANT_PLAYER_SPEED` to access the speed of all players.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the static from that variable, if a variable is static, it's belong to the class, not to instances.

**And making a static variable protected doesn't make any scene, since, inheritance and static are totally different.**

```
protected float speed;
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but In rest of code i need access to speed without creating any object. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also have an abstract method, which would mean that you would always have to override it in your sub classes.

```
public abstract class Dynamic {

protected float speed; 

abstract void setSpeed();
}
public class Player extends Dynamic{
@Override
void setSpeed() {
    this.speed=50;
}
```

}